# SQL SUM Aggregation with DISTINCT Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table 1: Schema for the bookworm database. Primary keys are underlined. There are some foreign key references to link the tables together; you can make use of these with natural joins.

```
Author(aid, alastname, afirstname, acountry, aborn, adied).
Book(bid, btitle, pid, bdate, bpages, bprice).
City(cid, cname, cstate, ccountry).
Publisher(pid, pname).
Author_Book(aid, bid).
Publisher_City(pid, cid).
```

This question has me a little confused, any help is much appreciated.

Find the number of authors of each country.

So far I have tried

```
SELECT 
     SUM(DISTINCT acountry) AS total,
     COUNT(DISTINCT acountry)AS N 
FROM Author;
```

And received:

> ERROR:  function sum(character varying) does not exist
>       LINE 1: select sum(distinct acountry) as total, count(distinct acoun...

**HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

Comment: You can't "sum" strings. What do you expect the "sum" of `'Arthur'` and  `'Zaphod'` to be? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ok I realize that now, thank you. What about using the count statement instead? @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: You need to use 'group' with aggregate functions

Comment: Im trying to come up with a table that displays the countries and the number of authors from each different country. @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `sum` strings. As `acountry` contains the string value (Assuming country name). And to get the `the number of authors of each country.` To get the country wise author count you need to use the `GroupBy` country name and count the rows within that group which you can try as below,

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalAuthor,
        acountry AS Country
 FROM Author
 GROUP BY acountry
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew i was going to have to use count instead of sum I dont know why I was thinking sum. I see why GroupBy is involved, it makes sense now..kudos

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nothing like that. Just typed it in hurry. I will change it to `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by country, and count the number of records for each group

```
SELECT acountry, COUNT(1) as NumberOfAuthors FROM Author GROUP BY acountry
```